# angular doesn't recognize es2022

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, ecma

I need to use the function ReplaceAll(), so I updated the file tsconfig.json.

```
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "ES2022.String",
  "dom"
]
```

and when I run npm start it show the error:

> error TS6046: Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6',
> 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020',
> 'esnext', 'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker',
> 'webworker.importscripts', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core',
> 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable',
> 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol',
> 'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object',
> 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string', 'es2017.intl',
> 'es2017.typedarrays', 'es2018.asyncgenerator', 'es2018.asynciterable',
> 'es2018.intl', 'es2018.promise', 'es2018.regexp', 'es2019.array',
> 'es2019.object', 'es2019.string', 'es2019.symbol', 'es2020.bigint',
> 'es2020.promise', 'es2020.string', 'es2020.symbol.wellknown',
> 'esnext.array', 'esnext.symbol', 'esnext.asynciterable',
> 'esnext.intl', 'esnext.bigint'.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're using an older version of TypeScript that doesn't support ES2022. You need to update TypeScript, for example, with the following command: `npm install typescript@latest`.

Comment: what if you can't update it in the project?

Comment: I am using Typescript 4.9.5, well above 4.6 when ES2022 support was added, and still have this issue.